# overlapping of images in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Please Help as I update image of user 1 as abc.jpg then if I update user 2 hobbies then its profile pic is replaced by the user 1 image don't know why?

```
public function multiple_image_upload()
        {
            $config = array();
            $config['upload_path']          = './uploads/user_avatars/';
            $config['allowed_types']        = 'gif|jpg|png';
            $config['max_size']             = 10000;
            $config['max_width']            = 10240;
            $config['max_height']           = 7680;

            $images = array();
            $count = (count($_FILES['avatar']['name'])>0);
            if($_FILES['avatar']['name']!= Null && ($count = count($_FILES['avatar']['name'])) > 0)
                //using this its working fine but my images are overlapped

            {
                $files = $_FILES;
                $images = array();
                /* check if folder with year exists*/
                $current_year = date('Y');
                $path = './uploads/user_avatars/'.$current_year;

                if(is_dir($path)){
                    /* do nothing */
                }else{
                    /* create directory */
                    @mkdir( $path , 0755, true );
                }

                $images = array();
                for($i = 0; $i < @$count; $i++) 
                {
                    $config['upload_path'] = $path;
                    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png';
                    $config['max_size'] = '100000';
                    $config['max_width']  = '102400';
                    $config['max_height']  = '76800';
                    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

                    if ($this->upload->do_upload('avatar'))
                    {
                        $data = $this->upload->data();

                        /* create thumbnail */
                        $this->load->helper('image_thumb_helper');
                        generate_image_thumb($data['full_path'],$path,$data['file_name']);

                        /* add to database */                   
                        $images[$i]['file_name'] = $current_year.'/'.$data['file_name'];
                        $images[$i]['thumb'] = $current_year.'/thumb_'.$data['file_name'];
                    }else{
                        $this->form_validation->set_message('multiple_image_upload',$this->upload->display_errors());
                        return false; 
                    }    
                }

                $this->session->set_userdata('uploaded_images',$images);
                return true;
             }
            else{

              return true;
            }
        }
```

Above is my code I need help for solving this

```
    if($_FILES['avatar']['name']!= Null && ($count = count($_FILES['avatar']['name'])) > 0)
```

main issues is in this I guess but not sure

Comment: So do you get two separate images uploaded i.e can you see them in your upload folder and do they both have the correct names?

Comment: on folder insert only once

Comment: if the user profile pic is empty and i update any field of the form then automatically replace its empty pic with previous one i have updated for other user

Comment: So only ever one image is physically uploaded and it's always being overwritten with the latest image that you upload. That would mean that the filename does not change. I'm talking only about the actual image files... not what you see on your webpage...

Comment: yes the previous image is overwritten

Comment: but it also insert them in db that's why they were displaying

Comment: Ok, so what filename do you get of this single overwritten image in the upload folder?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126617/discussion-between-timbrownlaw-and-ghugu).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, check the count of $count variable. Then keep below 
If($_FILES['avatar']['name']!= NULL && count($_FILES['avatar']['name'])> 0)

I don't know why you are using for loop? If they are only one image then $i will be 0. So, always it is replaced with first one.

Comment: whcih image is deleting?